# Practice or practise?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, spelling

I learnt in Merriam-Webster and other reliable sources that advice differs from advise. *Advice* is a noun while *advise* is a verb. Same goes with the words *device* and *devise*.

However, the word *practice* does not differ from *practise* as stated by the Merriam-Webster Dictionary. Is it true? Or the rule is still the same like on the words advice and advise? Here are some examples the Webster Dict. used:

> You need to practice what you preach.- It is a verb because it entails that
>   you need to apply or carry out what you have been preached.
>
> Being a good musician takes a lot of practice- It is used as a noun
>   because it entails a systematic exercise for proficiency in music.

Answer (score 1):

Surprising to me, practice is used for the noun and practise is for the verb, except in the U.S. where "practice" is used for both. So you would be best off only writing "practice" if you are in the U.S. since most people will think "practise" is a misspelling.

[Source](http://grammarist.com/spelling/practice-practise/)